# Application throws java.lang.StackOverflowError Exception in Activity

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh, stack-overflow, android-viewgroup

I am working on one Android application. in my one activity i am using PullToRefreshListView. sometime i am getting **java.lang.StackOverflowError** Exception on my activity. i have tried to fix it and i also searched on google too but not getting perfect solution.

i have two activity with same functionality with PullToRefreshListView with same data. but i am getting this Exception on only one activity. other activity is working fine.

Here is my full StakeTrace.

Please help me. Sorry for my poor English.

Thankx in advance.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError  
at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:749) 
at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:972) 
at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:416)  
at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:295)  
at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:269)  
at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:942)  
at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:405)  
at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:400)  
at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5038)  
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10982)  
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10421) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10985) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10421) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.widget.ListView.drawChild(ListView.java:3223) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2092) 
at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3218) 
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView$InternalListView.dispatchDraw(PullToRefreshListView.java:293) 
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10985) 
at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3398) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10421) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10985) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10421) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10985) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10421) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10985) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10421) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10985) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10421) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:928) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10985) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10421) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10985) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10421) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10419) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2850) 
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489) 
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10985) 
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2126) 
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10421) 
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:842) 
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1943) 
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1667) 
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2475) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: When is this happening? You should also share your activity code and layout xml.

Comment: @helleye : when loading activity. i think this is the issue with nested layouts ( described by Saras in below comment )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the reason why StackOverflow Exception occurs is due to nesting of Layouts. But this issue will occur only upto 4.0 and below, beyond that stackoverflow exception will not occur much. Check if you have multiple nested layouts in your xml to avoid this issue. Please post your xml in order to help further.

Comment: i think you are right. i am reducing layout heirarchy. it should be fix now. and this issue is arise in Android 4.1.1. working fine with 4.2.2 and other ICS and JB devices.

Comment: I am also getting this error due to complex layout hierarchy using the Android 4.2.2 but in above I am not getting